# Как предотвратить компиляцию import'ов?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Мне нужно скомпилировать `.test.ts` файлы, но при этом основной проект я уже собрал и при каждом изменении тестов мне его пересобирать не нужно. Я попытался сделать это таким образом:

`tsconfig.test.json`

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.dev.json", // компилирует всё, кроме .test.ts
    "include": ["src/**/*.test.ts"],  // используем тот же конфиг, но только для .test.ts
    "exclude": [],                    //
    ...
}
```

Но несмотря на то, что я указал в конфиге, что компилировать я желаю только `.test.ts` файлы, оно компилирует в том числе и `import`'ы. Как сделать так, чтобы `tsc` мне верил "на слово", что импортируемые скрипты уже скомпилированы?

---

`src/a.ts`

```typescript
// какой-то библиотечный код
```

`src/a.test.ts`

```typescript
import {
    // ...
} from './a' // импорт, из-за которого a.ts повторно компилируется

// какой-то тестирующий код
```

До компиляции (я уже компилировал с `tsconfig.dev.json`, с `tsconfig.test.json` - ещё нет):

```
projroot
├─...
├─tsconfig.dev.json
├─tsconfig.test.json
├─src/
│ ├─a.test.ts
│ └─a.ts
└─dist/
  └─a.js             // результат компиляции tsconfig.dev.json
```

После компиляции (с текущим `tsconfig.test.json`):

```
projroot
├─...
├─tsconfig.dev.json
├─tsconfig.test.json
├─src/
│ ├─a.test.ts
│ └─a.ts
└─dist/
  ├─a.test.js        // результат компиляции tsconfig.test.json
  └─a.js             // tsconfig.test.json также задевает и этот файл, т.к. он импортируется в
                     // a.test.ts, заставляя его повторно компилироваться, хотя его нет в include
```

После компиляции (с изменённым `tsconfig.test.json`):

```
projroot
├─...
├─tsconfig.dev.json
├─tsconfig.test.json
├─src/
│ ├─a.test.ts
│ └─a.ts
└─dist/
  ├─a.test.js        // результат компиляции tsconfig.test.json
  └─a.js             // результат компиляции tsconfig.dev.json
```

Comment: нужно использовать `exclude`

Comment: @Grundy и как? я вот думал, писать это, или нет: думал, и так очевидо, что простым `"exclude": ["src/**/*.ts"]` не отделаешся...

Comment: так ты должен указать какие файлы ты хочешь исключить.

Comment: @Grundy я не хочу вручную указывать каждый файл, который я хочу исключить! как 1-м паттерном выделить все `*.ts`, но при этом не выделять `*.test.ts`? да я сомневаюсь, что exclude тут поможет...

Comment: конечно, это не помогло. я добавил конкретное имя файла в exclude, и оно всё равно компилирует, потому что, я более чем уверен, что через include и exclude ты выделяешь только руты для компиляции, а не вообще все файлы, что будут в `dist`'е

Comment: там можно указывать что-то вроде регулярного выражения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опция `noResolve` выполняет поставленную задачу, однако выбрасывает море исключений из-за того, что импорт не найден, хотя всё до этого уже было скомпилировано. Спрашивается, зачем тогда такая опция?

---

Единственное решение, что я нашёл, это использовать watch-mode через опцию компиляции `"watch": true`. Добавив дополнительно опцию `"listEmittedFiles": true` можно проследить, что оно действительно компилирует только изменённые файлы, но оно производит компиляцию не когда я закончил изменение, а когда файл сохраняется, а т.к. я использую VS Code с авто-сохранением, то оно будет нагружать мою машину постоянно без необходимой надобности.

---

Конечно, второе решение лучше, чем первое, но всё же, так сложно было привязать компилируемые файлы хотя бы к Git'у? Чтобы оно проверяло, какие исходные файлы были изменены и на основе этой информации производить компиляцию. Или же использовать банальную хэш-сумму? Ладно, этим вопросам всё равно суждено быть затерянными в бесконечном потоке issues на их исходной репке...